# how to delete written data from external storage?

Tags: android

I'm using following function to write a object to external storage.

After using it i want to delete that object from external storage to free memory. 
Can any one guide me what should i do?

```
public boolean saveObject(List<DalCategories> obj) {
   if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
      cacheDir=new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"MyCustomObjectForSearchFilter");
   } else {
      cacheDir= getCacheDir();
      if(!cacheDir.exists()) {
         cacheDir.mkdirs();
      }
      final File suspend_f = new File(cacheDir, "test");
      FileOutputStream fos = null;
      ObjectOutputStream oos = null;
      boolean keep = true;
      try {
         fos = new FileOutputStream(suspend_f);
         oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
         oos.writeObject(obj);
      } catch (Exception e) {
         keep = false;  
      } finally {
         try {
            if (oos != null) {   
               oos.close();
            }
            if (fos != null) {  
               fos.close();
            } 
            if (keep == false) {
               suspend_f.delete();
            }
         } catch (Exception e) { 
            keep = false;
         }
      }
      return keep; 
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case...

```
final File suspend_f=new File(cacheDir, "test");
boolean success = suspend_.delete();
// the success variable will have TRUE if the file was deleted
```

Comment: after calling .delete method it will remove directly that file from external storage?

Comment: Also, unless there's some reason you need to have it on the external storage I'd use getCacheDir() in all cases. This ensures that nothing goes wrong should the user unmount the card while you're writing to it and also ensures that the file will get deleted when you're uninstalled.

Comment: could you please explain last option ? how file will get deleted when uninstall of application is takes place?

Answer (score 0):

Use Java file I/O to [delete files](http://exampledepot.com/egs/java.io/DeleteFile.html) or [directories](http://exampledepot.com/egs/java.io/DeleteDir.html).

Answer (score 0):

You could call [deleteOnExit()](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/java/io/File.html#deleteOnExit%28%29) on the file objects. This will tell the virtual machine that the files can be deleted after the virtual machine ends. This will not free up the space immediately but after the app is closed (which can take some time on android). If there is no sensible data in the files this should be an easy and fail save solution.